# Is Orphan Black's 5th season going to be its last?

Tags: orphan-black

Being a fan from the beginning, I was sorry to hear the news that the show has been cancelled. Does this mean that the 5th season will be its last?

Comment: Have you read the Wiki page? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_Black

Comment: Thank you sounds as if going past the next season has possibility. However when I watch it on BBC america they always say the final season meaning the one up next.

Comment: Welcome to Movies Stack Exchange! I have suggested an edit to make this question less time sensitive and a bit more objective.

Comment: @Catija Asking the OP to check Wikipedia sounds very similar to asking them to just Google it, which is [discouraged on Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/191265). For all we know, this poster could be asking on this site to find a source that they can add to Wikipedia.

Comment: @Thunderforge There's a difference between posting LMGTFY links and asking someone if they've checked the Wikipedia page for something. A question like this is often simply addressed by doing a tiny amount of research and "[show your work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97880/is-lack-of-other-research-a-reason-to-downvote)" is also something encouraged on SE... including being the likely reason why this question has been downvoted. It's possible that the OP was unaware that Wikipedia generally has this information, so pointing that out would in fact be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The show has been renewed for a 5th and final season .

From [this](http://www.ismyshowcancelled.com/article/2016-06-16/orphan-black-renewed-for-final-season/):

> BBC America, along with Canadian partner Space, announced today that the sci-fi drama has been renewed for a fifth and final season. The networks have ordered 10 last episodes to conclude the series in 2017, with its co-creators promising an "epic conclusion to the tale of Sarah and her clone sisters"

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense even though I enjoy the series I wondered how the writers could justify their premise without falling into a category equivalent of lunacy. This would be a crying shame considering the brilliance of the first season. By season two the cracks were apparent. Even so showed talent.

Comment: No problem! and I agree about season 2, imo it was very disappointing and I stopped watching after it. Now I'm thinking of start watching it again!